# jQuery menu aim - Sub menu did not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

According to [this plugin](https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim), here is what I have tried :

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Explore the Monkeys</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li data-submenu-id="submenu-1"> <a href="#">Department1</a>
            <div id="submenu-1" class="popover">
              <!--<h3 class="popover-title">Category1</h3> -->
              <div class="popover-content">
                <ul>
                  <li>cate1</li>
                  <li>cate2</li>
                  <li>cate3</li>
                  <li>cate4</li>
                  <li>cate5</li>
                  <li>cate6</li>
                  <li>cate7</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li data-submenu-id="submenu-4"><a href="#">Department4</a></li>
          <li data-submenu-id="submenu-5"><a href="#">Department5</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is CSS :

```
    .popover {
        width: 400px;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        border-top-left-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;   
    }
    .popover-content {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .dropdown-menu {
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        border-top-right-radius: 0px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }
```

Problem : Sub menu of `Department1` shows only `cate1,2,3,4` and `cate5,6,7`.
[image]

Any one know, how can I display `cate5,6,7` on the right of `cate1,2,3,4` like Amazon navigation menu.

Comment: Depending on what your needs are you could give https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count a try.

Comment: So cate 5,6,7 should be part of the cate 1-4 list, but on the right side of it, correct?

Comment: @AndrewIce : yeah, you're right.

Comment: @JoshPowell : so did I have to put `column-count:3;` in `.popover-content `?

Comment: Give this a try, `.popover-content ul { column count goes in here for the ul }`. Also if you want 2 columns you prob should use 2 instead of 3.

Comment: @JoshPowell : I tried it, but nothing has changed.

Comment: @Domo Did you included each browser prefix like, -webkit- and -moz-?

Comment: @JoshPowell : Wow! added those prefix, it works very well. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Domo No problem! The last thing you need to consider is browser support. `column-count` is fairly new and does not have great IE support besides 10+. If old browsers are a must then Andrew Ice's answrer *should* do the trick.

Comment: Ah... I'm not yet testing it on IE.

Comment: One more thing, how can we display Department list without click on `Explore the mobkeys`? Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution would be to add a new ul for every x amount of children.
Therefore:

```
<ul class="main">
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>cate 1</li>
            <li>cate 2</li>
            <li>cate 3</li>
            <li>cate 4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>cate 5</li>
            <li>cate 6</li>
            <li>cate 7</li>
            <li>cate 8</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And of course the css is simple:

```
ul.main > li{
    float: left;
}
```

The css for making one list break like that is possible but would be very hacky.

Comment: i see... but after this static list, I will change those data with dynamic data, so add new ul is a bit problem for me.

Comment: Depending on how you're adding the elements, you could use your server code or javascript, or even a mixture of the two, to grab every 4 items and create a new li and ul with those 4 menu items you've received.

Comment: Oh ok, I will try it and let you know whether it's being solve or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Providing a fiddle would help greatly!

As for how you may fix this issue by adding:

```
.popover-content {
   text-align: center;
   height: 100%
}
```

Comment: Is there more associated CSS? You will need that :P

Comment: Aww! what is that CSS?

Comment: In the fiddle it looks like it is missing some of the styling compared to your screenshot

Comment: I think I had included all of those css :|